# Unity AndroidJavaClass.CallStatic<Enum> on Android plugin. Is this possible?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an old Flurry plugin to work with the new Flurry Android SDK.
I'm trying to call this "logEvent" on Flurry .jar file

```
static FlurryEventRecordStatus logEvent (String eventId)
```

The FlurryEventRecordStatus is an enum, like this:

```
enum FlurryEventRecordStatus { FlurryEventFailed, FlurryEventRecorded, FlurryEventUniqueCountExceeded, FlurryEventParamsCountExceeded, FlurryEventLogCountExceeded, FlurryEventLoggingDelayed }
```

On my Unity C# code I want to do something like this:

```
Enum status = FlurryAgent.CallStatic<Enum>("logEvent", eventId);
```

But this obviously doesn't work.

Is there a way to get this *enum* from java as a Return Type directly from Unity?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post :( but for future reference:
I ended up just using 'AndroidJavaObject' for the return type and calling: `flurryAgent.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("logEvent", eventId);`